# .htaccess not working in Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache Web Server and Node.js app

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to set up a password-protected staging environment for a Nodejs/Express API server and web app server through the use of Apache HTTP Server and .htaccess.

**However, the configuration below is not working, and I am able to access the Nodejs server via curl and the browser (port 80) without any restriction or password prompt.**

My Nodejs app is located at `/var/www/html/nodejs/app.js` and is running via `pm2` on port `8080`.

I've placed my .htaccess file in `/var/www/html/.htaccess`, and it has the following content:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
AuthUserFile /home/user/safedirectory/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Please Enter Password"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

My Apache config is located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and has the following content:

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full

    <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    </Location>

    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

I've run the commands

```bsh
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
```

and

```bsh
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

but to no avail.

FYI, I've used the following sites as resources:

- [How to use the .htaccess file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file)
- [Set Up a Node.js App for a Website With Apache on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/application/misc/set-up-a-nodejs-app-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu-1604/)
- [How To Rewrite URLs with mod_rewrite for Apache on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [How To Use Apache as a Reverse Proxy with mod_proxy on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-2-%E2%80%94-creating-backend-test-servers)
- [How To Install the Apache Web Server on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `.htaccess` if you have access to Apache configuration files. You can find the explanation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when).

In your case, `.htaccess` is even not applied since requests never reach the folder, they are immediately proxied.

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia Full

<Location />
        AuthUserFile /home/user/safedirectory/.htpasswd
        AuthGroupFile /dev/null
        AuthName "Please Enter Password"
        AuthType Basic
        Require valid-user

        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```